# HibernateException: Missing table: Metadata / Session on Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

When I try to map Oracle (11g) table with name "Metadata" or "Session" using JPA in Spring Boot application I get:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: Metadata / Session

Session is restricted word in Oracle, but Metadata not.
Other tables works fine.
This shouldn't be a problem with my code, because when I move that DB to postgres, all work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was find source of problem.
When you want use table name like Metadata or Session in Oracle you must insert that name in additional quotes, then all work.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"Metadata\"")
@XmlRootElement
public class Metadata implements Serializable {
...
}
```